# Parcelable array event parameter problem for GTM

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I try to create a simple custom tag for catching "purchase" events from Firebase Analytics. My tag config is below.

```
Tag Type : Function Call
ClassPath : com.xx.xx.GTMProvider

Key                  -   Value 
items                -   {{Items-Custom}}
action_type          -   FBevent
class_name           -   NmEventPurchase
```

{{Items-Custom}} is for the key "items" which was added in Variables section.

The problem is whenever I trigger the code below;

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
Bundle item1 = new Bundle();
item1.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "ABCD123");
item1.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings");
item1.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants");

Bundle item2 = new Bundle();
item2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1234");
item2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "boots");
item2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "shoes");

Parcelable[] products = new Parcelable[]{item1,item2};
params.putParcelableArray("items",products);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE, params);
```

I got the error below;

**E/GoogleTagManager: Internal error - Function call: __md_main Type not supported: class [Landroid.os.Parcelable;**

If I just send a string (for example json string) instead of parcelable[] for the items param, everything is just working fine. **I need to findout how to add a custom variable which contains a mixed array type in GTM Console.**

I am really stuck at this point and there is no any explanations about the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS: Tag Manager Android dependency : **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'**

Thank you all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all and just for consistency, where you put your items into the bundle  your should use `params.putParcelableArray(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, products);`

instead of: `params.putParcelableArray("items",products);`

> I need to findout how to add a custom variable which contains a mixed array type in GTM Console.

Unfortunately in enhanced ecommerce you cannot add custom parameters to your bundles.

About your error, you should be using ArrayList instead of Parcelable. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce#product_impressions). It should look something like this:

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);
params.putParcelableArrayList(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, items );
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE, params);
```

Comment: Thanks Nil, I thought the samefor adding custom parameters to bundles, but wasn't so sure about it. Great explanation thank you.

Comment: no problem. I'm glad it helps. Accept my answer if it solved your problem please. Thanks!